# PyDNS & DNS timeout error

Tags: python, dns

Per [validate_email 1.3 : Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email), in order to check the domain `mx` and verify email exits, I must have the [pyDNS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydns) package installed.

How do I set my own name service (DNS) instead of system one as I'm getting timeout otherwise...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you would set your DNS server to, for example, [Google's public DNS server](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/):

```
from validate_email import validate_email
import DNS
DNS.defaults['server']=['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']

print validate_email('rob@example.com', check_mx=True)
```