# Python DNS library - DNS.Base.TimeoutError: Timeout

Tags: python, dns

I'm using Python DNS library ([pydns 2.3.6 : Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydns)) and I'm getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3.py", line 8, in <module>
    if validate_email(line[0],check_mx=True,verify=False):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validate_email.py", line 134, in validate_email
    mx_hosts = get_mx_ip(hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validate_email.py", line 102, in get_mx_ip
    MX_DNS_CACHE[hostname] = DNS.mxlookup(hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DNS/lazy.py", line 51, in mxlookup
    l = dnslookup(name, qtype = 'mx')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DNS/lazy.py", line 34, in dnslookup
    result = Base.DnsRequest(name=name, qtype=qtype).req()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DNS/Base.py", line 231, in req
    self.sendUDPRequest(server)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DNS/Base.py", line 260, in sendUDPRequest
    r=self.processUDPReply()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DNS/Base.py", line 119, in processUDPReply
    raise TimeoutError, 'Timeout'
DNS.Base.TimeoutError: Timeout
```

How do I handle errors such as this within script?

Answer (score -1):

You have to set an address to a DNS server. Check the following link:
[PyDNS & DNS timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488288/pydns-dns-timeout-error)